# How to set show admin bar front to true for all users?

Tags: users, user-meta, admin-bar

I just wanted to know whether it is possible to set for all users `show-admin_bar_front` meta data to true. 
I've tried this to put those lines in functions but with no results :

```
// Create the WP_User_Query object
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query(array('role' => 'Subscriber'));

// Get the results
$users = $wp_user_query->get_results();

// Check for results
if (!empty($users)) {
    // loop trough each author
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        // add points meta all the user's data
        update_user_meta(5, 'show_admin_bar_front', 'true');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `update_user_option()` function ([see codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_option))

Your loop looks fine to me, so probably this would work:

```
// Create the WP_User_Query object
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query(array('role' => 'Subscriber'));

// Get the results
$users = $wp_user_query->get_results();

// Check for results 
if (!empty($users)) {

    // loop trough each author
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        // update option
        update_user_option( $user->ID, 'show_admin_bar_front', 'true');
    }
}
```

Things to pay attention to:

1. You're looping through all queried users, so in `update_user_option`
   the first parameter needs to be the id retrieved from current user
   object (not the hardcoded ID)
2. The third parameter in `update_user_option` should be of a string type apparently, so `"true"`, not `true`

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your answer. I put it in my functions.php with no result.

Comment: Hello again, sorry for my mistake - apparently you need to set the option to 'true' - it's a string after all, not boolean. I've just tested this and it works fine. I've updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. But it's kind a strange because It doesn't work on the first 300 users...
Could it be that they never activated so the user's meta does not even get updated ?

Comment: No, i don't think so - i'd bet that it was caused by the server timeout if your site is big. By default `WP_User_Query ` will try to loop through all of your users: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php#L179. You might wanna try to limit the number of users retrieved at once using the `number` parameter and move to next batch with `offset` parameter.
In general performing operations on big sets of data are best done with WP CLI, not inside your functions.php: https://wp-cli.org/

Comment: Thanks a a lot. It was definitely that. 
I 've used "include" and "exclude" parameters from the  `WP_User_Query` to update users bt batch and it works like a charm. Thx